# Where are Profiles stored in Wine 1.6?

Tags: wine

I am running several programs via Wine 1.6, and I need to get into the data that they would normally store under the users profile in Windows, i.e., the "AppData/Local" folder.

Everywhere I have looked says that this is in the "Profiles" folder in .wine/drive_c/windows.

But I do not have a "Profiles" folder there. I have looked and looked, but no where can I find the user profiles that are stored for Wine programs. Anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows the AppData folder is located in C:\Users\yourname\AppData. That folder is hidden away.

In Wine the AppData folder is located at `/home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/users/yourname/`.  To find the folder open "Files" (which opens to `/home/$USER` for your user).

The `.wine` folder should be here but, it is hidden. To unhide it, press CTRL+H. Now you should see the `.wine` folder.

Next, open and goto `drive_c` and you should see the folders `Windows`, `users`, `Program Files`, and `Program Files (x86)`. Open `users` and navigate into your folder.

You should now see `Application Data`.